# How do you select the last visible element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery and I want to select the last visible element with some class e.g. 'target'

how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var e = jQuery('.target:visible:last');
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but I didn't realize that it was this easy..

I found the answer after googling it

```
$('.target:visible:last');
```

Comment: I'll try to do that next time :)